# CSV/JSON data imported to dynamic table

Tags: json, import, table, csv

I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to turn a CSV or JSON data file into a table on the front-end of a website. Ideally the data would be imported into the database and then output into a table on the front-end.

I've dabbled with the plugin FeedMe, but the issue is that it has to fit into a pre-defined table. Is there any way to import this data into a table that creates columns based on the data?

The exact scenario I have is that I'm uploading a sheet of points standings that include each weekend's points accumulation and the final column is the total season points. As each weekend is finished, that new weekend is inserted as a column, thus growing the table's columns which Craft's table field can't do dynamically.